Dharma Artha Kama Moksha
I am doing meditation (breathing 2 hours daily) for last 6 years. My question is does meditation helps in Artha and Kama , or just its for moksha ? Actually my age is 30 . So I am now interested in more in Artha and Kama not so much on moksha .

Do you try Patanjali's ashtānga yoga?

Regulation of the breath destroys both positive as well as negative karmas, so yes. Performing any yogic practice correctly will automatically give the desire for Moksa as the nature of the self & this creation will awaken in the Sadhaka.

@Marmayogi anapana and vipassana

@Harihara I dont want moksha I want artha and kama

It'd inevitable due to the power of yoga. Yes, one attains artha and kama as well.

@ShriHarivansh https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anapanasati not anushthan

@quanity I suggest you anushthan instead of mindful breathing and do pranayam instead

If your mind is inclined towards mundane, then you are free to use your skillset gained using anapana/vipassana meditation methodologies, to the advantages of Artha and Kama.  However, Gautama Buddha taught these techniques for liberation from samsara (the cycle of rebirth).
